# Trigger and sequence-assigned ID in a range of numbers

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I'm trying to write a trigger in SQL Developer that when something is entered in the Student table, a student ID number is generated that starts with an "S" and is between S500 and S999.

I get an error

```
Error report:
Unknown Command
```

when I try to compile the trigger to just generate a number, and I can't quite figure out how make it only generate a number between S500 and S999 (my attempt is dashed out as a comment in the code below).

This is my first time writing a trigger, and I was trying to go off of another example (same idea but with employee IDs instead of student IDs and without the 500-999 constraint) but am unsure where I'm going wrong. I looked for related stack overflow questions but couldn't find any that specifically dealt with the 500-999 part.

Any ideas or help would be much appreciated!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER students_seq
  BEFORE INSERT 
  ON STUDENTS 
  FOR EACH ROW
  DECLARE
  temp_studentID students.studentID%type; 
  BEGIN
  SELECT LPAD(to_char(student_seq.nextval), 4, 'S000') INTO temp_studentID FROM 
  dual;
  :new.studentID := temp_studentID;
  -- update_studentID ( some_studentID, 999); want Student IDs to begin with S500 and go to S999
  END;
  /
```

Comment: What you have works, though it has some unnecessary steps. Not sure why you see that error. How are you running this, as a statement or script, and in which client since you tagged with both SQL Developer and PL/SQL Developer?

Comment: Hi Alex, I'm running it as a statement and in SQL Developer.

Answer (score 1):

What you've shown works to set the student ID from the sequence (not quite how I'd do it, but more on that later). To restrict the value you can set a maximum for the sequence:

```
create sequence student_seq start with 500 maxvalue 999;
```

You can then use your trigger, or a variation like mine below. As an aside, using the same name for different objects is going to be confusing, so I'd rename your trigger. This all works, run as script in SQL Developer:

```
create table students (studentid varchar2(4), name varchar2(20));

create sequence student_seq start with 500 maxvalue 999;

create or replace trigger students_trig
before insert on students 
for each row
begin
  select 'S' || to_char(student_seq.nextval, 'FM000') into :new.studentid
  from dual;
end;
/
```

Or if you're using 11g or later you can assign directly to the column:

```
...
begin
  :new.studentid := 'S' || to_char(student_seq.nextval, 'FM000');
end;
/
```

You can then see the values being used:

```
insert into students (name) values ('Bob');

1 row inserted.

insert into students (name) values ('Alice');

1 row inserted.

select * from students;

STUDENTID NAME               
--------- --------------------
S500      Bob                 
S501      Alice
```

If I discard a load of sequence values to get to the end of your range, so currval is 998, then I can only insert one more row:

```
insert into students (name) values ('Charlie');

1 row inserted.

insert into students (name) values ('Diane');

SQL Error: ORA-08004: sequence STUDENT_SEQ.NEXTVAL exceeds MAXVALUE and cannot be instantiated
...

select * from students;

STUDENTID NAME               
--------- --------------------
S500      Bob                 
S501      Alice               
S999      Charlie
```

You are prevented from creating a student with an ID outside the range. You could define the sequence to wrap back around to 500 but then you'd have to deal with clashes with existing values.

Comment: thank you Alex! your in-depth answer helped me out so much and taught me what I was going wrong!!